# how to merge result into single row with case mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Good day,

I have a query that tallies total amount of sales per month.

```
SELECT v.id, v.name, MONTH(g.trans_date) AS m,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 1 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS jan,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 2 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS feb,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 3 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS mar,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 4 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS apr,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 5 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS may,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 6 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS jun,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 7 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS jul,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 8 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS aug,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 9 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS sept,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 10 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS octx,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 11 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS nov,
COALESCE( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = 12 THEN SUM(g.debit - g.credit) END,0) AS dece
FROM vendor_table AS v
LEFT JOIN transaction_details AS g ON g.vendor = v.id
WHERE CODE IN ('dr#') 
AND account IN (20) 
AND YEAR(g.trans_date) = 2022 
GROUP BY v.id,m
```

the above gives me this result [image]

as you can see on the image, I got 2 rows of Trading corp coz I have 2 transactions on different months.. is there a way to merge this with mysql w/o doing something like

`left join (select sum(debit-credit) as sales from transaction_details where MONTH(date) = 1  group by vendor) as jan on jan.vendor = vendor.id` x 12 for every month coz I think the 2nd one would be a slow query.. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: add `v.name` on the group by ?

Comment: hi @JorgeCampos I tried adding v.name on group by but I still get the same result.

Comment: So then the cause is either that you likely have two rows in the `vendor_table` for the `v.id` 270 and one of them does not have an equivalent on the transaction_details, thus the duplicate OR one of the rows linked with it doesn't have a month between 1-12 (maybe null)

Comment: Hmm i only have 1 row on vendors table with ID (270) but I have 2 rows on my `transaction_details` table but with different month, first being on january (m = 1) and the other one is on november ( m=11 ).. My goal mainly is to merge this two transaction being tallied into 1 row, so jan cell and november cell would have values instead of them being separated in two rows..

Comment: Then you have to remove the month from the group by, as it is being summed up

Comment: You need in `SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.trans_date) = xx THEN (g.debit - g.credit) ELSE 0 END)`, it seems.

Comment: I can attain this result by doing 12 left join selects but I think its not efficient to do with large data..  Im just wondering if I can get the same result with just doing case statement.. if its not possible then I guess I have to just loop the result with php and then group them from there..

Comment: again, remove the month from the group by and select statement, that will give the result you need

Comment: .. also remove `m` from both GROUP BY and output list.

Comment: Ohh... It actually worked @Akina .. Thanks for MAN!! I did not know that you can do sum with cases!  and  also jorgeCampos !! Appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of @Akina and @jorgecampos.. I was able to have the correct query

```
SELECT v.xid, v.name,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 1 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS jan,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 2 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS feb,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 3 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS mar,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 4 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS apr,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 5 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS may,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 6 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS jun,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 7 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS jul,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 8 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS aug,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 9 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS sept,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 10 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS octx,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 11 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS nov,
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(g.date_at) = 12 THEN (g.debit - g.credit) END),0) AS dece
FROM vendor_table AS v
LEFT JOIN transaction_details AS g ON g.vendor = v.xid
WHERE CODE IN ('dr#') 
AND account_id IN (113) 
AND YEAR(g.date_at) = 2022 
GROUP BY v.xid,v.name
```

[image]

Comment: (Accept your own answer)